# JLabel does not align the text in the center

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, boxlayout

Is there anything wrong in this code?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JLabel lab = new JLabel();
lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
lab.setText("TESET");
panel.add(lab);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to change the Color of JLabels to see their placement.  The Label may not have been added the way you inteded

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the future, a proper SSCCE should include the main() method and the import statements so we don't need to do any extra work to test your code.

```
//lab.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
lab.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Horizontal alignment is for the text within the bounds of the label.

AlignmentX is for the component alignment within the parent container.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! And will keep the SSCCE in mind next time! :)

Comment: This is, I believe, a BoxLayout thing. Setting AlignmentX/AlignmentY is necessary with BoxLayout.